# Why Retrofit give the correct result after second time?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am currently using Retrofit 1.9.0 for my Android App. I have developed a REST Service. In order to get the data from REST, I have implemented the following code. I would like to get the list of staffs based on the IDs string from server side.

```
if(!ids.isEmpty()) {
     retrofitService.getNewStaffInfo(ids, new Callback<List<StaffInfo>>() {
                 @Override
                 public void success(List<StaffInfo> staffInfos, Response response) {
                    System.out.println(staffInfos.size());
                    for (StaffInfo staff : staffInfos)
                        mStaffInfo.add(staff);
                    // update the local database
                }
                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }
     );
}
System.out.println(mStaffInfo.size());
```

However, my problem is, I get the result two times. At first time, the size of result's list is zero but at the second time, I get the correct result which is not zero.

I would be thankful, if anybody has a solution, why the the size of list's result is zero at first time?

Answer (score 0):

When using a callback, the code in the callback does not run until the network request is complete.  Meanwhile, your program continues to run code.  In your case, you launch the call, and before it is done try to print out the size of your list.  Then, when the call completes, you print the size of the list again.  I've annotated the problem line below.  Removing it will only print the correct size once.

```
if(!ids.isEmpty()) {
     retrofitService.getNewStaffInfo(ids, new Callback<List<StaffInfo>>() {
                 @Override
                 public void success(List<StaffInfo> staffInfos, Response response) {
                    System.out.println(staffInfos.size());
                    for (StaffInfo staff : staffInfos)
                        mStaffInfo.add(staff);
                    // update the local database
                }
                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }
     );
}
System.out.println(mStaffInfo.size());  <---- *** This line runs before the call back and prints out the zero size.  Remove it.
```